# Group Policy to set desktop background to say machine name

Tags: group-policy

Is there a way to easily set in group policy for each of the machines in our domain to say the machine name on the desktop background?  Our users log into multiple machines in a day and tend to get confused which one is which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a default Group Policy to display the hostname on the desktop.

An alternative is to use a utility, such as [BgInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx), in either a startup/Run registry key/logon scrip/etc to add information to the desktop wallpaper.

[image: BgInfo example]

Comment: Yeah, I just found bginfo and the host name property on it.  I just need to figure out now how to set it to not be profile specific.

Comment: What do you mean "profile specific"? If you want it to run for *everyone* that logs into a machine, add it to either `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. This can be done easily with Group Policy Preferences.